# State and city populate Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here Country, State and City filter dropdown lists are there. I dont want country. I want only state and city dropdowns. If I select state it should populate the appropriate cities.

Only in india state and cities I want. Can anyone please help me to do this.

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9YG1Ae6xagq6R3QHIfR?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.countries = {

                'USA': {
                    'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
                    'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
                    'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
                },
               'India': {
                    'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
                    'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
                    'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
                },
                'Australia': {
                    'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
                    'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
                }
            };

 $scope.GetSelectedCountry = function () {
                $scope.strCountry = document.getElementById("country").value;
            };
            $scope.GetSelectedState = function () {
                $scope.strState = document.getElementById("state").value;
            };
            $scope.GetSelectedcity = function () {
                $scope.strCity = document.getElementById("city").value;
            };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <label for="country">Country *</label>
 <select id="country" ng-model="statessource" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries"
                ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
 <option value=''>Select</option>
</select>    
 <label for="state">State *</label>
<select id="state" ng-disabled="!statessource" ng-model="model.state" ng-options="state for (state,city) in statessource"
         ng-change="GetSelectedState()"><option value=''>Select</option>
 </select>
  <label for="city">City *</label>
 <select id="city" ng-disabled="!model.state" ng-model="model.city" ng-options="city for city  in model.state"
         ><option value=''>Select</option>
 </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Can anyone please update this code.

Comment: Can't you just remove the code that does the country drop-down?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value to `$scope.statessource` in your controller after defining `$scope.countries` something like this `$scope.statessource = $scope.countries.India;`. You can remove the country dropdown if you do not want the user to change the country.